# How do I get values from a diffrent document in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to merge two XML files via XSLT Version 1.0 . My Problem here is, that I need to add the Attributes of the 2nd XML-file to the Attributes of the first file. Let me give you an example to clarify my Problem.

XML1:

```
<sample>
  <tag a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4" />
  <tag a="2" b="3" c="4" d="5" />
</sample>
```

XML2:

```
<sample>
  <tag e="5" f="6" g="7" />
  <tag e="10" f="12" g="11" />
</sample>
```

Output:

```
<sample>
<tag a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4" e="5" f="6" g="7" />
<tag a="2" b="3" c="4" d="5" e="10" f="12" g="11" />
</sample>
```

I tried following XSLT for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ws="http://www.w3schools.com">
<xsl:template match="/">                
 <xsl:for-each select="sample/tag">
<tag>
    <xsl:attribute name="a"><xsl:value-of select="@a"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="b"><xsl:value-of select="@b"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="c"><xsl:value-of select="@c"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="d"><xsl:value-of select="@d"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="e"><xsl:value-of select="document('xml2.xml')//@e"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="f"><xsl:value-of select="document('xml2.xml')//@f"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="g"><xsl:value-of select="document('xml2.xml')//@g"/></xsl:attribute>
<tag>
</xsl:for-each>

 </xbrl>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I got only the first line of the 2nd XML-File. EG my Output was:

```
<sample>
<tag a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4" e="5" f="6" g="7" />
<tag a="2" b="3" c="4" d="5" e="5" f="6" g="7" />
</sample>
```

Hopefully anyone can help me with this. I am completly new to XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short and easy way is using the following template applying a one-to-one position mapping:

```
<xsl:template match="/sample">
  <sample>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tag" />
  </sample>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
  <tag>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('a2.xml')/sample/tag[$pos]/@*" />
  </tag>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sample>
  <tag a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4" e="5" f="6" g="7"/>
  <tag a="2" b="3" c="4" d="5" e="10" f="12" g="11"/>
</sample>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can simplify things by starting off with the XSLT [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy the existing nodes and attributes in your first XML

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, to add the extra attributes to the `tag` element, you have a template matching `tag`

```
 <xsl:template match="tag">
```

In this, you then need to get the position of the current element, so you can find the relevant `tag` element in the same position in the second document

```
<xsl:variable name="position">
    <xsl:number />
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, you can select the attributes from the second document like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('xml2.xml')/sample/tag[position() = $position]/@*"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="tag">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="position">
                <xsl:number />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('xml2.xml')/sample/tag[position() = $position]/@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any Chance to avoid the <xsl:number />? Since I'm using it for really big XML files and <xsl:number> slow's it down by a lot. But the XSLT works pretty well.

Comment: See zx485's answer for how. Note how there is an explicit `<xsl:apply-templates select="tag" />`. This is necessary because otherwise `position()` would be affected by whitespace nodes, or other elements under `sample`.